# How can I implement this punch out from Bixby to Android App?

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

In my Bixby capsule I'm offering the user to open my Android app to handle more complex tasks. For this I'm constructing an intent when the user taps on on-click of a cell-card, which looks like this:

```
cell-card {
  [slot1, slot2, etc...]
  on-click {
    intent {
      [my intent...]
    }
  }
}
```

I want to implement this in a less intrusive way (see screenshot below), however I haven't been able to find a way how to construct an intent from a single-line. **Are there any official guidelines or documentation on how to implement a punch out?**

[image: Punch out to Android App]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That component is the `attribution-link` ([documentation](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/layout-macro-def.content.attribution-link))

Here is some generic code to help you implement it:

```
attribution-link {
  label {
    template ("Open in XYZ")
  }
  url ("YOUR URL HERE")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that is exactly what I was looking for. For anyone else looking, here are the official guidelines for punching out to an app: https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/design-guides/design-principles.ux-policies